# Nodejs - Joi Check if string is in a given list

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm using [Joi package](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v10.1.0/API.md) for server side Validation.
 I want to check if a given string is in a given list or if it is not in a given list.(define black list or white list for values)
sth like an *"in"* or *"notIn"* function. How can I do that?

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    firstname: Joi.string().in(['a','b']),
    lastname : Joi.string().notIn(['c','d']),
});
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are looking for the `valid` and `invalid` functions.
v16: https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=16.1.8#anyvalidvalues---aliases-equal
v17: https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anyvalidvalues---aliases-equal

As of Joi v16 `valid` and `invalid` no longer accepts arrays, they take a variable number of arguments.

Your code becomes

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    firstname: Joi.string().valid(...['a','b']),
    lastname: Joi.string().invalid(...['c','d']),
});
```

Can also just pass in as `.valid('a', 'b')` if not getting the values from an array (-:

Comment: in joi/hapi there is no option like valid or invalid :|

Comment: @BadriDerakhshan: If you're talking about `@hapi/joi` then there is no `@hapi/joi` anymore! that package got deprecated last month & Joi is officially back to Joi. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) (Also valid and invalid do exists in `@hapi/joi`)- which is kind of frustrating as users has to switch from Joi to @hapi/joi last year and in a year again back to Joi :-)

Answer (score 31):

How about:

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
    firstname: Joi.string().valid(['a','b']),
    lastname : Joi.string().invalid(['c','d']),
});
```

There are also aliases: .allow and .only

and .disallow and .not

Comment: This no longer works as 'valid' no longer accepts arguments of type array

Answer (score 2):

This works in [2023]:

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    status: Joi.string().valid("pending", "in-review", "resolved")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update from 10 Oct 2022**
Now valid function requires Object

```
Joi.string().valid({ ...values_array }),
```