# Joi check if string is in existing array - Typescript

Tags: typescript, joi

I am using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) for my project server side validation.

I have an array which is populate from database for eg:

```
let s = ['a','b','c'];
```

Now I need to check if for a given field the values is within the array `s` only. like this:

```
Joi.object({
    value:  Joi.string().valid(...s).required()
});
```

I used [Nodejs - Joi Check if string is in a given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41408469/nodejs-joi-check-if-string-is-in-a-given-list) as reference, but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Joi.string(...).valid is not iterable (cannot read property
> Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

However, when the values are hardcoded, it works perfectly:

```
Joi.object({
   value:  Joi.string().valid('a','b','c').required()
});
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: try ```
Joi.object({
   value:  Joi.string().valid.call(s).required()
});
```

Comment: I get  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'allow' of undefined` on build

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Array() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array):

```
const s = new Array("1", "2", "3");

const schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.string().valid(...s).required()
})

schema.validate({ a: "1" }) // valid
schema.validate({ a: "555" }) // invalid
```

If you want to keep your variable `a` , you can do this:

```
const a = ["1", "2", "3"];
const s = new Array(...a);
```